# split the dataframe for train and test SKlearn

Tags: python, dataframe, scikit-learn

I have `dataframe` with **1,600,000** rows like this

```
sentence      type

aaaaaa         A
bbbbbb         B
cccccc         B
aaaaaa         A
```

and I want to use this `dataframe` to train and test my model ( `%75` for **training** and `%25` for **testing** )

this is my code on `colab`

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

train, test = train_test_split(orgDF, stratify=orgDF['type'], train_size=0.75)
```

but when I run this cell, I got this `error`

> ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [2, 1600000]

Comment: This code should work, the problem is that you might have override the `orgDf` variable in a previous cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your feature is `sentence` and output is `type`.

```py
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X = orgDF['sentence']
y = orgDF['type']
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X, y, stratify=orgDF['type'], train_size=0.75)
```